# Is it safe to mix 2016/2022 as domain controllers?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, domain-controller, windows-server-essentials, windows-server-2022

We have a 2016 Server Essentials PDC, and now we'd like to add another DC for failover/backup purposes.

Will it be OK to use 2022 Server Standard for this second DC? (Web searches are returning answers to just about every question except this specific one.)

Comment: Generally speaking AD is supported on a platform for the life of the platform. There also haven't been that many changes in AD since 2016.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.

> [Windows Server 2016 functional levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/active-directory-functional-levels#windows-server-2016-functional-levels)
>
> Supported domain controller operating systems:
>
> - Windows Server 2022
> - Windows Server 2019
> - Windows Server 2016